# How to check If array is empty in Object and the other fields at the same time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iteration

Suppose I have object that looks like that :

```
filter: {
masterName: '',
service:[],
}
```

How can I check If array and masterName field is empty ?

Comment: check the array length and string length.

Comment: Use the [logical AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND).

Comment: what types of value can filter object has except array and string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just evaluate the `length` property of each of them to see whether the length is 0, as shown in the following example:

```js
var filter = {
  masterName: '',
  service: [],
}

// Checks whether masterName is zero-length
if (filter.masterName.length === 0) {
  console.log('masterName is empty');
}

// Checks whether service is zero-length
if (filter.service.length === 0) {
  console.log('service is empty');
}

// Checks whether either are zero-length
if (filter.masterName.length === 0 && filter.service.length === 0) {
  console.log('Both are empty');
}
```

String length is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) as:

> The length property of a String object contains the length of the
> string, in UTF-16 code units

Array length is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) as:

> The length property of an object which is an instance of type Array
> sets or returns the number of elements in that array.